# Keep div in the dead center of the page, no matter the size of neighbouring divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center 3 elements in the middle of a footer. One of them needs to stay in the dead center of the footer, no matter the size of his neighbors. The thing is now, the group as a whole is centered, but I want the middle one to be in the center, while the left and right ones should  'stick' next to it, one in the left and one in the right. **JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/xbqz8od2/

```html
<div class=container>
  <div id=left>No matter how big the left or right text gets</div>
  <div id=center>KEEP ME IN THE DEAD CENTER</div>
  <div id=right>foobar</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#left,
#right,
#center {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#left {
  background-color: salmon;
}
#center {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flex: 1;` to the left and right elements.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#left,
#right,
#center {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#left {
  background-color: salmon;
}
#center {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left, #right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div id=left>No matter how big the left or right text gets</div>
  <div id=center>KEEP ME IN THE DEAD CENTER</div>
  <div id=right>foobar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept the answer, but it's missing something, `display: block; text-align: right;` on the left element, so it makes the text 'stick' next to it https://jsfiddle.net/v3dfqpzm/

Comment: Well technically you mentioned that the _elements_, not the _text_, should stick to the middle element 

Comment: You are right, it was hard to explain the whole thing. Anyway, I left the comment for the posterity.